# How to use YII models for update one sql counter?

Tags: sql, model, yii

I'm very new with YII and I don't get it. 
I have an error with the system that I got. I have to update an SQL rows counter.
sql table:

> tbl_questions => answercount

I have this code that may modify it:

```
$model = Questions::model()->findByPk($id);
                    $model->answercount += 1;
                    $model->save(false);
```

The problem is, that: This solution don't do anything. How can I find the problem, or what's the solution? May I could use a good tutorial for this.

Comment: I found this one:`saveCounters(array('visits'=>1));` .. So is this the solution?
`$model->saveCounters(array('answercount'=>1)); $model->save(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YII, there are three ways to update counters.

1. Model->save();
2. Model->saveCounters();
3. Model->updateCounters();

For all these methods, we have to get the object before performing the updating process. i.e.,

```
$obj = YourObject->model()->findByPk($id);
```

Difference among them:

1. $obj->visits += 1; 
   $obj->save();
2. $obj->saveCounters(array('visits'=>'1'));
3. $obj->updateCounters(array('visits'=>'1', **'id'=>$id**));

The Trick is:
Better to use `saveCounters()`

If you use `updateCounters()`, make sure you have put id in a **condition** as highlighted in the code. Otherwise, **the 'visits' field for all records +1.**

You can also refer this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/282/using-counters-with-activerecord/) for more details.

Comment: You can also up-vote the solution. So that other user think its helpful and side by side I'll get reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->answercount += 1;
$model->attributes = array('answercount' => $model->answercount);
$model->save();
```

To debug do try the following in your config:

```
'db'=>array(
         …
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be one or more errors relating to the save operation.  The process you are carrying out *should* save the updated data to the database, but there may be issues with the update or other errors preventing the save from being carried out.

Try the following

```
if(!$model->save())
{
    throw new Exception("Error saving model : " . var_export($model->getErrors(), true));
}
```

This will raise an exception if the save operation is failing, and perhaps we can go from there.